# Differentiate ListView Items, ListActivity(Android)

Tags: android

How to differentiate between different items in list view, using `ListActivity(Android)`. For example I want to change the text color of different items based on some conditions.

Can any body please give me some sample code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code for ListView adaper:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView;
        EntSaleDocumentDetails entSaleDocumentDetails = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.myLayout,
                    null);
        } else {
            rowView = (View) convertView;
        }


        TextView myTv= (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvCode);

        myTv.setTextSize(16);

        //....

        // set selected item
        LinearLayout ActiveItem = (LinearLayout) rowView;
        if (position == selectedItem)
        {
            ActiveItem
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_dark_blue);
        }
        else
        {
            ActiveItem
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border02);
        }
        //....
}

public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
        selectedItem = position;
    }
```

your custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/border02"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/back_color_selector03"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TextView" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCode"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llProductDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/back_color_selector_blue_simple" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnProductDetails"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:src="@drawable/prd_details" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tblProductDetails"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvQty"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLblQty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvStockQty"
                    android:layout_width="100dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLblStockQty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMablagh"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLblMablagh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFee"
                    android:layout_width="100dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLblFee"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        adapter.setSelectedItem(position);
        myListView.invalidateViews();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how to define **`custom adapter`** for android listview?

If you don't then try to define an adapter class by extending BaseAdapter or any other adapter class. Inside that you will get **`getView()`** method, and in this method you can do every aspect of programming for the particular list item.

Comment: thnx .. i am new to android, can u plz elaborate with a sample code, highly appreciated.

Comment: @Arfin you can find examples for ListView here: http://goo.gl/Rbnhz, go through every articles for customizing listview, its one time practice only to understand and prepare custom adapter, because in future you just has to change very less in adapter class.

Comment: Thnx Paresh. Will try the same, if any doubt I'll let u know.